# How to return a Set View of Keys with existing Values?

Tags: java, hashmap, set, key, keyset

for example if I have a HashMap with 10 keys, but only 4 keys have a value. How can I return a SetView of these keys. I only found the Map<K,V>.keySet()-method but this method is giving me EVERY Key in this Hashmap.
I only need the ones with value !=null !!!
Sorry for my bad English, im German :)

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 2):

### Streams

1. Iterate over entrySet
2. Ignore null values
3. Collect the keys

```java
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
            .map(Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

### Use for loop

```java
        Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getValue() != null) {
                keys.add(e.getKey());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't use `Objects.nonNull()` like this, use a plain old `!= null` check. As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) says *"This method exists to be used as a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)"*, meaning that it exists as a convenience to be used as a method reference where a `Predicate` is expected.

Comment: @Andreas, Sure. thank you for sharing the information. I will update the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use the keySet() method, and loop through each Entry in the Set, checking the value of the Entry each time. If this "value" is null, then we remove it from the Set.

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet = new HashSet<>(yourMap.entrySet());
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : entrySet){
       if(entry.getValue() == null){
            entrySet.remove(entry);
       }
}
```

The resulting Set "entrySet" is what you're looking for

Comment: Error 1: `entrySet()` returns a *view* of the map, so when you call `remove()`, you're removing the entry from the map itself. --- Error 2: Calling `remove(entry)` while iterating will cause `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for the errors. But your second error isn't right, it doesn't throw ConcurrentModificationException. But your first error is valid, I edited the code so that it only CLONES the entry set :)

Comment: Javadoc of [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html): The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` method are *fail-fast*: if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` method, the Iterator throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future. Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed

Comment: *"The resulting Set "entrySet" is what you're looking for"*. Not really, since the question specifically mentions that it wants a "keySet".